# bootstrap not working on firefox / Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, firefox

site working perfectly on chrome the issue is that it does not on ie and firefox the layout seems to be different / styles are not applied what am i missing ive added the html5 shiv / "respond.js"
I've tried changing the if statement to match all ie versions still no luck.

website url 
*** resolved Thanks ***
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML document on line 19, change type="text/stylesheet" to type="text/css".

Comment: Oh my God you are awesome idk how i did not see that thank you thank you thank youuu i owe you a beer :D